How to manage notification with one state
This is a React project with Mantine's Notification System demo. It has a lot of function components using notification.
const A = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    notifications.show({
        // config
    });
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
const B = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    notifications.show({
        // config
    });
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
const C = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    notifications.show({
        // config
    });
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};

Now, we have a global state named muteMode, if user enable the state, all notification disabled. So I have to change code as below
const A = () => {
  const { muteMode } = useGlobalState(state => state);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (muteMode) {
      notifications.show({
        // config
      });
    }
  }, [muteMode]);

  return <></>;
};
// The B、C function components are same as A

I think is not good code. Because I have modify all business about notifications. If I add more business about notification, I have to modify again. Does something like Notification Manager exist?

What you can do is wrap notifiction.show() in a function of your own. Now that function handles things based on muteMode's value. So essentially you are creating an abstraction layer (you might call it a manager). But this sounds like an opinion based question since you are looking for different "good code" approaches

You can create a custom hook so that you don't have to rewrite everywhere. Example -
const useNotification = (config) => {
  const { muteMode } = useGlobalState(state => state);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (muteMode) {
      notifications.show(config);
    }
  }, [muteMode, config]);

  return null;
};

In your component use it like this -
const A = () => {
  useNotification({ title: 'Notification A' })

  return <></>;
};

const B = () => {
  useNotification({ title: 'Notification B' })

  return <></>;
};

const C = () => {
  useNotification({ title: 'Notification C' })

  return <></>;
};

Hope this helps!
